# Javascript/php carousel not working properly

Tags: html, php, javascript, image

I'm writing a slideshow/carousel for a webpage. I just started having PHP iterate through a folder of images, so that I can use the slideshow for an undefined number of images. Unfortunately, since making the change to a PHP for-loop, my JavaScript that should be starting the slideshow over when it reaches the last photo isn't working. I have a feeling that my use of the PHP is messing up my DOM structure, but I'm not sure how to figure out if that's the issue, and, if it is, how to fix it. Here's the PHP:

```
<div class="slider">
        <?php
            $output = '';
            $dir = dirname(__FILE__).'/img';
            $images = scandir($dir);
            if($images)
            {
                foreach($images as $image)
                {
                    if(in_array($image,array('.','..'))) continue;
                    ?>
                    <div class="slide slide-feature">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="img/<?php echo $image ?>" ></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
```

And Here's the JS that should allow me to move through the photos:

```
var carousel = function() {
    /*$('.tabs').children().children().click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('.active');
        $(this).addClass('.active');
    });*/
    $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
        if(nextSlide.length == 0)
        {
            nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
        }
        currentSlide.fadeOut(750).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(750).addClass('active-slide');
    });
    $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();
        if(prevSlide.length == 0)
        {
            prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
        }
        currentSlide.fadeOut(750).removeClass('active-slide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(750).addClass('active-slide');
    });
};

window.onload = carousel();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks,
Zachary Mason

Comment: Probably want to take this question over to StackOverflow. Also, probably want to display the HTML that gets output by the PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was just missing a  and as a result was accidently adding my arrows to the list of images that it was trying to display... Thanks anyway!